# php calendar that connects to database mysql for events

Tags: php, mysql

So i have code for a very simple calendar, however I can't figure out how to query mysql database to find any events for each day of the month. I know how to query the database for that information, but i dont know where i would put it in the code of creating a calendar or how to structure it or anything. ive looked at many codes of php calendars and for each code i havent been able to get data from my database, i just have no idea how to do it. any help is grateful, thanks.
calendar code editted to include db stuff:

```
include ("connection.php"); 

$date =time (); 
$day = date('d', $date); 
$month = date('m', $date); 
$month = $month + "02";
$year = date('Y', $date); 
$years = substr($year, 2, 2);

$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year); 
$title = date('F', $first_day); 
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day); 
switch($day_of_week){ 
    case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
    case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
    case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
    case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
    case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
    case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
    case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
}

$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
echo "<table border=1 width=294>";
echo "<tr><th colspan=7> $title $year </th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td 
width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td 
width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>";
$day_count = 1;
echo "<tr>";

while ( $blank > 0 ) 
{ 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    $blank = $blank-1; 
    $day_count++;
} 
$day_num = 1;
 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) 
{ 

echo "<td> $day_num <br/>";


$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, length FROM hire WHERE day = '$day_num' and month =    '$month' and year = '$years'") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

```
$time = $row['time'];
$length = $row['length'];

}

if (isset($time) and (isset($length))) {
 echo "Time: " . $time . "<br/> Length: " . $length . "<br/>";
}

"</td>";



    $day_num++; 
    $day_count++;
        if ($day_count > 7)
        {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $day_count = 1;
        }

} 

while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 ) 
{ 
    echo "<td> </td>"; 
    $day_count++; 
} 

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put your database code to the place where the date cells are outputted. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include ("connection.php"); 

$date =time (); 
$day = date('d', $date); 
$month = date('m', $date); 
$month = $month + "01";
$year = date('Y', $date); 

$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year); 
$title = date('F', $first_day); 
$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day); 
switch($day_of_week){ 
    case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
    case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
    case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
    case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
    case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
    case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
    case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
}

$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
echo "<table border=1 width=294>";
echo "<tr><th colspan=7> $title $year </th></tr>";
echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>";
$day_count = 1;
echo "<tr>";

while ( $blank > 0 ) 
{ 
    echo "<td></td>"; 
    $blank = $blank-1; 
    $day_count++;
} 
$day_num = 1;
 while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) 
{ 
    //database code here
    $result = ''; //formatted html result
    echo "<td> $day_num $result</td>"; 
    $day_num++; 
    $day_count++;
    if ($day_count > 7)
    {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $day_count = 1;
    }
} 

while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 ) 
{ 
    echo "<td> </td>"; 
    $day_count++; 
} 

echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: hmm, but the results for each day depend on the day, so when i query the database, day = $day_num and month = $month? currently in my database the data is as a date format e.g 2013-03-01, id have to change that to store a day value, month value and year value instead?

Comment: well it prints the words "time: " and "length: " but without any results and prints it above the calendar lol, but the code gives results for time and length when not within the calendar, any ideas?

Comment: oh i've managed to get it within the calendar now, however it doesnt produce results, only if i take the code out of the calendar to test it :s

Comment: ive got data to show, but the output is either no data, or when it finds data on that day, it then outputs the data for that day and every day after until the next new piece of data...

Comment: You need to find if `$result` returns data.ie                `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);//mysql_
if ($num_rows >0) { 
  echo "<td> $result </td>"; 
}else{
 echo "<td> $day_num </td>"; 
}`  If using PDO [SEE](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @user1938174 david is right. You need to check whether the data is available before you show it.